# Draw a dot always at a fixed point on screen, even when the Canvas is zoomed in or out? - Android

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-drawable, android-screen

I now draw a dot on the canvas, which may be zoomed in or out.

As far as I know, the drawing function, `canvas.drawCircle()` takes in the coordinates in canvas coordinate system. Furthermore, the co-ordinates remain unchanged when the canvas is zoomed.

E.g. previously you draw a dot at `(50, 50)` in the canvas coordinate system, and then you zoom in the canvas, the dot's coordinates in the canvas still remain `(50, 50)`. But obviously, the dot has been moved w.r.t. the screen.

**When the canvas is zoomed, the dot should be kept at the same position on the screen. **i.e.*** After the dot moves w.r.t. to the screen, I want to move it back to its original position w.r.t. the screen.*

My `onDraw()` function is as follows:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
    canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();

    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    mImage.draw(canvas); // draw the map as the background

            Paint PointStyle = new Paint();
    PointStyle.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    PointStyle.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    PointStyle.setStrokeWidth(2);

    canvas.drawCircle(Constant.INITIAL_X, Constant.INITIAL_Y, 3, PointStyle);

    canvas.restore();
}
```

**I tried the following method to move the dot back on screen after the scaling.**

```
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor(); // accumulate the scale factors
        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f)); // 1 ~ 10

        float pinToCornerOnScreenXDistance = 0;
        float pinToCornerOnScreenYDistance = 0;
        float canvasToScreenDiffRatioX = 0;
        float canvasToScreenDiffRatioY = 0;
        float pinOnCanvasX = 0;
        float pinOnCanvasY = 0;

        // pin's location on the screen --> S:(336, 578)
        pinToCornerOnScreenXDistance = 336 - canvasLeftTopCornerOnScreenX;
        pinToCornerOnScreenYDistance = 578 - canvasLeftTopCornerOnScreenY;
        Log.d("Screen Diff", "X: " + pinToCornerOnScreenXDistance + " Y: " + pinToCornerOnScreenYDistance);

        canvasToScreenDiffRatioX = canvasWidth * mScaleFactor / 720; // screen of HTC One X --> 720*1280
        canvasToScreenDiffRatioY = canvasHeight * mScaleFactor / 1280;
        Log.d("Ratio", canvasToScreenDiffRatioX + " " + canvasToScreenDiffRatioY);

        pinOnCanvasX = 0 + pinToCornerOnScreenXDistance * canvasToScreenDiffRatioX; // canvas left top corner is the origin (0, 0)
        pinOnCanvasY = 0 + pinToCornerOnScreenYDistance * canvasToScreenDiffRatioY;
        Log.d("Pin on Canvas", "X: " + pinOnCanvasX + " Y: " + pinOnCanvasY);

        Constant.setInitialX(pinOnCanvasX);
        Constant.setInitialY(pinOnCanvasY);
        historyXSeries.set(0, Constant.INITIAL_X);
        historyYSeries.set(0, Constant.INITIAL_Y);

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

The idea is based on the fact that I notice when I zoom in or out the canvas, its left top corner never moves. That is, **the canvas' let top corner is the zooming center.**

Then I successfully keep updating the zooming center's co-ordinates when the canvas is moved. So in this way, no matter I move the canvas or zoom it, I always have the zooming center's coordinates in my `canvasLeftTopCornerOnScreenX` and `canvasLeftTopCornerOnScreenY`.

Then I try to utilize the distance between the never-moved-during-scaling zooming center and the desired position where I hope to place my dot, `(336, 578)` here. I calculate it as `pinToCornerOnScreenDistance`.

As its name suggests, it is the on-screen distance. I have to scale it into canvas distance so that I can draw the dot, since the drawing function is based on the canvas coordinate system instead of the screen coordinate system. Currently, the code is device-specific, i.e. it is only for HTC One X, which has a 1280*720 screen, for now. So I  do the scaling as follows:

```
canvasToScreenDiffRatioX = canvasWidth * mScaleFactor / 720;
canvasToScreenDiffRatioY = canvasHeight * mScaleFactor / 1280;
```

Then, finally I calculate the new on-canvas coordinates of on-screen point `(336, 578)` and then draw the dot there.

But the result is not correct. When I zoom the canvas, the dot I draw fails to remain at `(336, 578)` on screen.

**Can anybody tell me where goes wrong?
Or propose another way of doing this?**

Any comment or Answer will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your app using full-screen? Otherwise, it is not 1280 for the height. But I don't think that is your problem.

Based on my understanding, I will change the code to

```
pinOnCanvasX = 336 / mScaleFactor;
pinOnCanvasY = 578 / mScaleFactor;
```

which I assume when mScaleFactor == 1, the pin that on Canvas are the same on screen

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,
I think this can be useful for your issue,

```
pinOnCanvasX = (336 * mScaleFactor) + trans_x;

pinOnCanvasY = (578 * mScaleFactor) + trans_y;

here, trans_x and trans_y is translation of canvas on x and y axis. here in your case should be mPosX, mPosY but not sure what these points means for.
```

> The way I would like to share you is scale and translate your starting
>   point of the circle as much as canvas does. That means if your canvas
>   scale and translate with some value then apply the same for
>   your starting point too.

hope this will solve your problem.